# Handling stability of very small currents

Tags: circuit-analysis

I saw this circuit somewhere and am wondering how to find an equation for the current of Ic2 in terms of circuit parameters such as Vcc.

[image]

For this circuit lets say that Q1=Q2=Q3, and that IS5=10*IS6 just to make I1=10I2=10I3. Here is what I can say in terms of equations:

$$I_2=\frac{1}{R_2}V_T\ln(\frac{I_1}{I_2})$$
But since 
$$\frac{I_1}{I_2}=\frac{I_5}{I_6}=10$$
I get 
$$I_2=\frac{1}{1k \Omega}25mV.\ln(10)=57uA $$

However, things get complicated if I'd have considered Q5=Q6, because that would have implied that I1=I2 and the first equation would give out zero amps, but that is not the case since I1 is a few hundredths of a microamp different from I2. Anyway, now that Q5=Q6 I'm not sure how to find an equation for I2. I guess that would be proportional to log(Vcc) but how?

The other thing is that at relatively low currents, of the order of a few microamos, which is the case when Q5=Q6 and R1=R2=1kohms, the Early effect comes up and a few Volts change in Vcc would result in significant change in I2. That now I2 highly depends on Vcc through Early effect is not desirable and I would like to know if I could take care of Early effect so that it doesn't affect the circuit's operation point. My idea is that since Vec3 is slightly more positive than Vec2 the change in I2 or I3 due to Early effect would be compensated If I would have made Vec2=Vec3. But don't know how to implement the idea.

Comment: This kind of bias current generation circuit has **two** solutions, one where \$I_x=0\$ and a second solution where the currents are non-zero. That's why this kind of circuit **always** needs a startup circuit to work properly. The low currents do not surprise me at all. The difference in \$V_{be}\$ between Q1 and Q2 appears across the 1k emitter resistor. This voltage is quite small. Combined with a 1 k resistor that gives a small current. Lower the resistor to 100 ohms and see what you get.

Comment: Also you're too "early" (pun intended) taking into account the Early effect, the solution can be found without taking the Early effect into account.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What range of currents do call "low"? Also I wanted to let only a 2uA current flow through the collector of Q3, with the condition that it stays insensitive to Vcc. Maybe in theory, I'm not considering practical situations.

Comment: If you want a lower current then simply increase the resistor. Complete insensitivity to Vcc is **impossible**. You can improve it though by keeping the Vce of the transistors which determine the current, constant. The standard solution for this is **cascoding**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Now if I lower resistors to 25 ohms the currents rise to 60uA. Again using the above equation I derived, I get I2=0A, which doesn't make sense. Of course, that equation assumed I1 != I2 and ignored other terms. Now what do you do to find I1 or I2?

Comment: I would use \$V_{R2}=V_Tln{\frac{I_{c1}}{I_{c2}}}\$. **Choose**  a value for I1 and I2 with \$I_{c1} = 10 I_{c2}\$. The voltage is equal to \$V_{BE,Q1}-V_{BE,Q2}\$ and that appears across R2. Then determine the required value for R2 using the \$I_{c2}\$ you chose.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry, take Q5=Q6. Also I want it to be related to Vcc so that I know how it changes with Vcc. It seems to me that it doesn't have a straightforward solution.

Comment: I expect it to be **very** difficult to find the \$I_{out}(V_{cc})\$ relation analytically. What is more feasible is a small signal analysis of that. Then you would get the small signal PSRR.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, it seems so. The only way that comes to my mind is to use a separate current source across the emitter or collector of Q1 to bias it. It will allow no need for analytical stuff. Anyway, thank you Bim for your time!

Comment: Just an aside, the early effect is the voltage coefficient of collector current. For Va = 100, Ic increases 1%/V. At Ic=1u, swinging Ic 2 Volts is an extra 20nA. At Ic=1 mA, swinging Ic 2 Volts is an extra 20 uA.

Comment: I see where you get your first equation. But where do you get the second ratio to equal 10? Where does the 10 come from?